# Word VBA to copy certain highlighted colors and paste in new document with no formatting lost

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that is 180 pages and uses all the highlight Colors randomly throughout the document. The document has several different formats on it from italics, bullets and underline and different size fonts.

What I am trying to do is filter through the document select all paragraphs that contain a certain color highlight then paste it in a new document keeping all formatting in place. It then loops through again and selects the next color highlight and pastes it in the same new document with a page break in between or just a new document all together. I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days.

I have tried the formulas from this [Word VBA copy highlighted text to new document and preserve formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235473/word-vba-copy-highlighted-text-to-new-document-and-preserve-formatting) and other ones on Stack Overflow but none of them preserve all the formatting or one that I found I could only get it to copy the whole document with formatting and paste in but not the selected highlights.

This one does the trick but it removes all formatting and can't figure out how to place page break in.

```
Sub ExtractHighlightedTextsInSameColor()
  Dim objDoc As Document, objDocAdd As Document
  Dim objRange As Range
  Dim strFindColor As String
  Dim highliteColor As Variant
  highliteColor = Array(wdYellow, wdTeal)

  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
  Set objDocAdd = Documents.Add

  objDoc.Activate

  For i = LBound(highliteColor) To UBound(highliteColor)
   With Selection
   .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
       .Highlight = True
      Do While .Execute
        If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = highliteColor(i) Then
         Set objRange = Selection.Range
         objDocAdd.Range.InsertAfter objRange & vbCr
         Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
      Loop
     End With
    End With
   Next
  End Sub
```

'This one only copies all text in document and not just highliteColor asked for

```
    Sub HighlightedColor()
    Dim objDoc As Document, objDocAdd As Document
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim highliteColor As Variant
    highliteColor = Array(wdYellow, wdTeal, wdPink)

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set objDocAdd = Documents.Add

    objDoc.Activate

    For i = LBound(highliteColor) To UBound(highliteColor)
      With Selection
      .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
          .Highlight = True
          Do While .Execute
            If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = highliteColor(i) Then
              Set objRange = Selection.Range.FormattedText
              objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
              objDocAdd.Content.FormattedText = objRange
            End If
           Loop
         End With
        End With
     Next

     End Sub
```

I expect the output to copy all text that are a certain highlight color, paste them into a new document preserving all formatting and then page break it. Go back select the next highlight color and paste in document until all colors are gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made adjustments to your code based on what I understand you want to do. In some cases I tried to make it a little more readable, for example I removed one of the With methods.

Look closely at the use of FormattedText and how it is transferred from one range to another. And also look at the end of the routine for how a page break is inserted.

```
Sub ExtractHighlightedTextsInSameColor()
    Dim objDoc As Document, objDocAdd As Document
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim strFindColor As String
    Dim highliteColor As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    highliteColor = Array(wdYellow, wdTeal)

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set objDocAdd = Documents.Add
    Set objRange = objDocAdd.Content


    For i = LBound(highliteColor) To UBound(highliteColor)
        objDoc.Activate
        Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
        objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Forward = True
            .Format = True
            .Highlight = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Execute
            Do While .found
                If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = highliteColor(i) Then
                ' the following copies only the highlighted text
                ' objRange.FormattedText = Selection.Range.FormattedText
                'if you want the entire paragraph that contains a highlighted text item then use this
                    objRange.FormattedText =  Selection.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.FormattedText

                    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    objRange.InsertParagraphAfter
                    objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                Else
                    objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                End If
                .Execute
            Loop
        End With
        objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If i < UBound(highliteColor) Then
            'added a conditional check so an extra page break is not inserted at end of document
            objRange.InsertBreak Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
        End If
    Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you did here? I am new to this so a little slow. I did try the code above and it doesn't copy the formatting over just the highlights over and when I have more then two colors it goes crazy and MS Word crashes. Not sure if doing something wrong.

Comment: @NakaMichie, I edited the code so it captures the entire paragraph of formatted text that contains a highlighted portion. Whether I use one highlight color or three or more colors, the code runs fine and does not cause Word to crash. You must have some other problem on your system.

Comment: Thanks think it was that computer I was on. Tried it in Word 2016 and worked great. Thanks!